# Play Core In-App Review API not showing the Review Activity

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-core

I'm trying to utilize the Review API (Play Core library 1.8.0) from Google which was just released yesterday.
See https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review

I followed the troubleshooting section carefully, I made sure the app is downloaded from the internal testing track, my account does not have a review on the app, the app is in the library of that user etc.. I even tried with a completely new account, but every time the com.google.android.finsky.inappreviewdialog.InAppReviewActivity is shown only to immediately disappear.

I'm calling the following code from the onResume() method of my activity:

```
                reviewManager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(AlarmClock.this);
                Logger.logInfo("Rating: requestReviewFlow() ");
                reviewManager.requestReviewFlow().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ReviewInfo>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ReviewInfo result) {
                        Logger.logInfo("Rating: launchReviewFlow() ");
                        reviewManager.launchReviewFlow(AlarmClock.this, result).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                                Logger.logInfo("Rating: launchReviewFlow() success ");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Both listeners return success.

Here is the log output:

```
2020-08-06 16:01:29.317 29618-29618/? I/MyApp: [06Aug 16:01:29.317, main]: Rating: requestReviewFlow()
2020-08-06 16:01:29.318 29618-29618/? I/PlayCore: UID: [10409]  PID: [29618] ReviewService : requestInAppReview (com.mypackage)
2020-08-06 16:01:29.320 29618-29774/? I/PlayCore: UID: [10409]  PID: [29618] ReviewService : Initiate binding to the service.
2020-08-06 16:01:30.081 29618-29618/? I/PlayCore: UID: [10409]  PID: [29618] ReviewService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.inappreviewservice.InAppReviewService})
***2020-08-06 16:01:30.082 29618-29774/? I/PlayCore: UID: [10409]  PID: [29618] ReviewService : linkToDeath***
2020-08-06 16:01:30.355 29618-29637/? I/PlayCore: UID: [10409]  PID: [29618] OnRequestInstallCallback : onGetLaunchReviewFlowInfo
2020-08-06 16:01:30.355 29618-29774/? I/PlayCore: UID: [10409]  PID: [29618] ReviewService : Unbind from service.
2020-08-06 17:02:21.590 7478-7478/? I/MyApp: [06Aug 17:02:21.590, main]: Rating: launchReviewFlow() 
2020-08-06 17:02:21.630 1511-4316/? I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.inappreviewdialog.InAppReviewActivity (has extras)} from uid 10122
2020-08-06 17:02:21.750 7478-7478/? I/MyApp: [06Aug 17:02:21.750, main]: Rating: launchReviewFlow() success
```

Anyone had success to make this working? Any tips. Big thanks!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue @Petr Nalevka If you find any solution please do share here

Comment: Many thanks I'm now trying a minimal implementation with my other app and will see..

Comment: I see the same issue. The syslog includes this Exception: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.play.core.review.b (with minifyEnabled = false!). Here is the link to the Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162969017

Comment: I successfully implemented the API on Android, it showed only on version released via Internal test track. I can send you code snippet @PetrNalevka. Btw I think it's wrong to trigger it in onResume, you should trigger it after you bring some value to the user, for example after setting an alarm in your case.

Comment: Same issue here! I guess this is still a lot buggy. Will implement it later on my apps.
@DavidVávra, post it here. Thanks.

Comment: @MPaulo Posted my code as an answer here.

Comment: it's working if I use a Gmail account.  My GSuite account doesn't work as it can't leave a review https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test#troubleshooting

Comment: Your code is fine. Wont show up by design. Check here how to test: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test

Comment: I decided to not use that api. Why should I risk with so valuable user reviews for no reason

Comment: I think there is some obfuscation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63650212/10117882

Comment: @orium the thing is if your app works well you also can get more good reviews, see it positive

Comment: @Petr Nalevka, There isn't a problem with your code.  The docs aren't comprehensive enough in explanation.  Your code should work reliably and repeatably.  I have given a detailed answer [right here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286540/play-core-in-app-review-api-not-showing-the-review-activity/65333746#65333746)

Answer (score 39):

Okay, I had exactly the same problem as described by the OP and as is listed on the issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167352813 and has still not been resolved as yet by GoogleDev.

Same UI manifestation(s), same log entries (incidentally, the log entries are the same when it works though, complete with the entry that says “ReviewService : linkToDeath”, but let’s not worry about that eh?)

The key thing, you'll no-doubt want to know though, to avoid too much suspense, is that **IT WORKS**.  *The in-app review API works!*  No need for me to repeat the block of code for calling the review flow, it is pretty much exactly the same as in the docs, similar to what the OP has listed, and several others have kindly repeated.

Took me a while, but I got to the bottom of it as follows, in a nutshell:

1. Your device needs to have the latest Google Play system update
2. Irrespective of whether your app is published on the Play Store **YOU ABSOLUTELY NEED TO DO YOUR TESTING VIA INTERNAL APP TESTING or SHARING** (I only did “Internal App Testing”, but I expect the same applies)
3. To debug your code with Android Studio, you need to have installed your Internal App Testing version on your device **AND RUN THE DEBUGGER SUCCESSFULLY WITH YOUR IAT VERSION STILL INSTALLED ON THE DEVICE AT LEAST ONCE**
4. Once you are up and running, when the review dialog pops up, you have to note that, if you submit a review, then you have utilised all your quota.  When you try and launch the review flow again it looks like the “problem” has returned.  You get “successful” launch but nothing shows.  If you have submitted a review (and this is why it absolutely needs to be in IAT), then it is only a “private review” (not seen publicly on your app page), and you need to **DELETE THE REVIEW TO GET THE POP UP TO SHOW AGAIN.**
5. You can select “Not Now” instead of "Submit" *ad infinitum* (well, I tried about two-dozen times) and the pop-up dialog will launch each time you (re)call the flow.

So, step-by-step fix:

1. Prepare your device by uninstalling your app, then ensure you have the latest Google Play Store update.  On my Sony Xperia X1 this is Settings->About Phone->Android version->Google Play system update.
2. Irrespective of whether the above restarted your device, **turn your device off and then back on again** (don’t restart - **off** then **on** i.e. cold boot).
3. Now go into Settings->Apps & notifications->Google Play->Storage & Cache, then do both **CLEAR CACHE** and **CLEAR STORAGE**.  (This should not affect any of your installed apps).
4. Create a signed release for IAT based on your In-App review code base.  You have to do this even if you have a release in production.
5. Now **install your **IAT RELEASE** on your device** - the words, "(Internal Beta)" or words to that effect, should be appended to your app name if you are downloading from the right location (i.e. IAT), (do not run it, just install)
6. In Android studio **Clean, Rebuild and Debug, your app on the device with the IAT version installed**.  If you get a message saying "The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature."  **DON'T CLICK OK TO UNINSTALL YOUR IAT VERSION**  Follow the instructions here: [Android: Error - App has same packaged different signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872959/android-error-app-has-same-packaged-different-signature).  The accepted answer is the correct one.  If you have to do this, please note you should do a **Clean and Rebuild->Debug** again.

Hopefully, now all should be okay.  Once you have done the above steps successfully, you can actually "clean" uninstall the app from the device on subsequent debugging sessions, and it will still work.

To test, and to delete a review note the following.  When you submit a review, you will be able to see it in Google Play Console (not under "Reviews", incidentally but) under "Testing Feedback".  Also you cannot delete your review under "Testing Feedback" it seems.  You need to delete it from your IAT download page **on the device**.  On there, under the heading **Your private feedback**, select the right-angled ellipsis thingy to the right of your review and simply "Delete".

Your pop-up will now show every time until you submit another review.  Voila!

Comment: We are having the same issue. However, for us it works with a @gmail.com email address and like a lot of other folks, it does not work with a Gmail Suite email (eg me@customgsuitdomain.com)

Comment: I think the Gmail Suite email account problem, which I have seen reported here is a separate issue.  I cannot really help with that one because I haven't tested this with a Gmail Suite account.

Comment: Just to follow up, we did get it work with our GSuite accounts using Internal App Sharing. Internal testing was where we were experiencing issues.

Comment: Interesting!  Again, I only did "Internal App Testing" although I still think of the GSuite account business being a separate issue - for which the answer may well be "don't use Internal App Testing for GSuite accounts, use Internal App Sharing instead"!  Thanks for the follow-up, could well be the answer for someone with the same problem!

Comment: how long do you have to use the app before the dialog appears (1 day, week, month, year) ?
I have the code, but never see the dialog.

Comment: suppose user has already submitted the review and triggers the in app review flow after a long time again, then will the review will appear to the user ?

Comment: @NipulSindwani. Yes.

Comment: @LanDenLabs - if the dialog is not appearing then your code is incorrect.

Comment: @Kofi - Does the rating dialog appears on first launch and every launch ? that does not sound right.  If so - then I definitely have something wrong with the code.

Comment: @LanDenLabs - see the very last sentence in my answer: "Your pop-up will now show every time until you submit another review..."

Comment: If the user has already rated the app(by going to the app page in the play store) and if i try to show that particular user "in-app" review dialog, will it appear or not?

Comment: There is a limit as to how often you can present a user with the dialog, and you have absolutely no control over that, so in the particular scenario you describe, you can assume not.

Comment: What does 'IAT' mean ??

Comment: "Internal App Testing"

Answer (score 24):

I have raised a issue on google issue tracker regarding this. I also have the same issue.

For more info check this my issue tracking url: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167352813

Comment: If the user has already rated the app(by going to the app page in the play store) and if i try to show that particular user "in-app" review dialog, will it appear or not?

Answer (score 15):

I also saw the same problem, my request review flow works, then the launch review flow works, but nothing displays (I do notice the small line at the center of the bottom of the screen appears briefly, and my audio cuts out briefly as the app is paused and then resumed but no review flow appeared).

I was able to get it to work by adding a user to my device that was not in my list of License Testers (Google developer console) and had not reviewed my app previously. I was able to display the rating popup once, I cancelled the operation so that I could test it again, but it would not reappear afterwards. It appears to be a one shot thing and they are aggressively guarding against annoying the user with review popups.

This feature doesn't seem useful for my case, I have a button on the settings screen to rate my app. Since I have no way of knowing what happened, I can't thank the user, I can't disable the button or display an "you already rated this thank you" message, and the button just appears to do nothing so it looks like a bug. I guess the intended use is to ask the user during gameplay, and if they cancel the dialog accidentally then it's just too bad for you.

Ideally Google should allow License Testing users to display this popup more than once for testing purposes.

Comment: Wow so it's basically garbage then! It's useless if it can only display once and we get no error info based on if there was already a review left, etc. Why not always show it and if a review has already been left, allow them to edit it?

Comment: @Flyview you know what? exaclty!

Comment: If the user has already rated the app(by going to the app page in the play store) and if i try to show that particular user "in-app" review dialog, will it appear or not?

Answer (score 13):

I just want to share the code that is working reliably today (2020-09-03). It was essentially copied from [the official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java)

```
ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(activity);
Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();
request.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    try {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // We can get the ReviewInfo object
            ReviewInfo reviewInfo = task.getResult();
            Task<Void> flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(activity, reviewInfo);
            flow.addOnCompleteListener(task2 -> {
                // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
                // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no
                // matter the result, we continue our app flow.
                utility.logMessageAsync(activity, "In-app review returned.");
            });
        } else {
            // There was some problem, continue regardless of the result.
            goToAppPage(activity);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        utility.logExceptionAsync(activity, "Exception from openReview():", ex);
    }
});
```

It was tested with internal app sharing on a Android 10. It never failed to show the review dialog.

Comment: have you test on signed abb or apk?

Comment: Yes, the internal app sharing in my case requires a singed apk.  I am not using abb for this app.

Comment: Works fine! I used it on abb in internal app sharing as Hong indicated. I tested using Android 7, 8, 9

Comment: been using it in the past week and a half and got good results (I show it after making sure that I'll get a good review) but in the last couple of days the numbers dropped sharply, I have no new ratings, I have indications that users are willing to review but no rating in the store, have anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: how long do you have to use the app before the dialog appears (1 day, week, month, year) ?
I have the code, but never see the dialog.

Comment: @LanDenLabs I am not aware of any time limits.

Comment: So when does the dialog appear, the first time you call the API, which would be silly because the user has no experience using the app to give a usable rating.  There must be a period during which the dialog is suppressed, like 1 week, or 1 month. 
Does anyone who has gotten this to work know how long after installing the app,  the dialog appeared ?

Comment: If the user has already rated the app(by going to the app page in the play store) and if i try to show that particular user "in-app" review dialog, will it appear or not?

Comment: I used the same but adding try-catch and callback for the `flow` object was a good idea. thank you!

Comment: @EliLeszczynski you need to add some logging to capture those logs to see what is happening to the user behaviour.

Answer (score 11):

I had same issue, I've followed below steps then **working fine**

1. If you mark stars and submit, then need to **remove your review** from
   play store.
2. Clear data for **Play Store**.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I solved with the next steps:

1. Adding my APK file to **internal testing channel**
2. Adding a tester user **with a gmail account** ex: *email@gmail.com*. GSuite mails don't work
3. With the tester mail, accept the tester privilege
4. With a physical device signed with the tester user email, go to Play Store and download the app

It works!!

**Note**: If App is not published yet, you could use Google Console **App Sharing**

Comment: Had the same issue. It took some time to figure out that GSuite accounts do not work.

Comment: Does anyone know why this is? The app I'm currently building, or any app for that matter, might have users with a GSuite email address. This seems like something that should be fixed.

Answer (score 8):

For all the users that needs a working JAVA code, please find my code below:

```
ReviewInfo reviewInfo;
ReviewManager manager;
```

OnCreate

```
manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this);

private void Review(){
    manager.requestReviewFlow().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ReviewInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ReviewInfo> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                reviewInfo = task.getResult();
                manager.launchReviewFlow(MainActivity.this, reviewInfo).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Rating Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Review Completed, Thank You!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "In-App Request Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Make sure the below is implemented:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0'
```

And please also note, that the dialog will only display if your app is in production, alpha or internal testing on the Google Play Console Account.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but when I use it, it says "Review Completed, Thank You!" without anything before that.  Can you tell me how to determine if the app is in production, alpha or internal testing?  When I go to the playstore, it says "You're a beta tester for this app".  I'm just testing the app locally on my own device.  Do I need to get myself off of the beta in order to test?

Comment: It worked once in production build, when I deleted and tried again to review it's not working

Comment: You shouldn't use the toast saying "Thank you". As per https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java the onComplete gets triggered when the flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no matter the result, we continue our app flow.

Comment: If the user has already rated the app(by going to the app page in the play store) and if i try to show that particular user "in-app" review dialog, will it appear or not?

Answer (score 7):

Try uploading your app to [Internal App Sharing](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/internalappsharing)

I have found that with the exact same apk uploaded to Internal Testing versus Internal App Sharing, the latter is more reliable in displaying the In-App Review Flow every time I try testing it.

You would need to enable **Internal app sharing** in the Play Store to be able to install your app from the link provided by uploading your apk.

Basically go to the Play Store, go to Settings, scroll down to Play Store version and tap it a bunch of times to "Become a developer", then enable Internal app sharing.

Comment: Yes yes yes, I tried everything and was about to give up but the Internal App Sharing worked, thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: If the user has already rated the app(by going to the app page in the play store) and if i try to show that particular user "in-app" review dialog, will it appear or not?

Answer (score 5):

In MY case, yes, this will not work if the account that’s being used already left a review.

HOWEVER, deleting the review from the Play Store doesn’t always work.  Something lingers.

So, unless you want to be sad, CLEAR THE PLAY STORE APP’S STORAGE EVERY TIME YOU DELETE THE REVIEW THAT’S LEFT.  You do not need to also clear the cache as well as others have suggested (clearing the storage will also do this), but clearing the Play Store app’s cache was not enough.  Once I did this, I could consistently test this ad nauseum.

Good luck.  What a mess this is.

Comment: Solved my testing problem,
clear the Google Play Store data cause to dialog appear again

Comment: Dec 2023, clearing the Storage (not cache) from Play Store works!

Answer (score 3):

My working code:

```
private fun askForReview() {
    val manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this)
    manager.requestReviewFlow().addOnCompleteListener { request ->
        if (request.isSuccessful) {
            val reviewInfo = request.result
            manager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo).addOnFailureListener {
                logWarning("In-app review request failed, reason=$it")
            }.addOnCompleteListener { _ ->
                logInfo("In-app review finished")
            }
        } else {
            logWarning("In-app review request failed, reason=${request.exception}")
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on an app from Internal Test track (there is no quota there).

Comment: This code worked in Live. But it didn't work in Test.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review) says

> To provide a great user experience, Google Play enforces a quota on
> how often a user can be shown the review dialog. Because of this,
> calling a launchReviewFlow method might not always display a dialog.
> For example, you should not have a call-to-action option (such as a
> button) to trigger a review as a user might have already hit their
> quota and the flow won’t be shown, presenting a broken experience to
> the user.

So you don't expect it to show the dialog every time  and also there's no way to know if the dialog is shown or not nor the user has reviewed your app or not either

Comment: There should be a way to test it reliably

Comment: Wow so it's basically garbage then! It's useless if it can only display once and we get no error info based on if there was already a review left, etc. Why not always show it and if a review has already been left, allow them to edit it?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear you are not using com.mypackage right?

```
2020-08-06 16:01:29.318 29618-29618/? I/PlayCore: UID: [10409]  PID: [29618] ReviewService : requestInAppReview (com.mypackage)
```

Ensure that the appId used is the one that it's "owned" (aka installed by) by the selected account in the Play Store in the device.

I believe the test guide (https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test) is clear in terms of how to test it given the different requirements.

My tips:

1. Use only one account in the device
2. Ensure that account has installed the app (appears in the app & games > Library section in Play Store)
3. The account is a GMAIL one, not a GSuit
4. You can review with the account if you go to the app play listing page.
5. The account has not reviewed
6. If you intend to use the Internal Test Track ensure the account has joined the test track.
7. When switching between different accounts and testing things out, sometimes might be helpful to "Clear Data" from the Play Store app.
8. Try all the above with different account

PS: You could test also the Internal App Sharing.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, the dialog never appeared to me ...

But even so, I left it implemented in the application and posted it on the Play store.

Then I downloaded and tested the version and everything works perfectly.

Comment: how long do you have to use the app before the dialog appears (1 day, week, month, year) ?
I have the code, but never see the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the cases are covered in other answers. I want to highlight few more troubleshooting Steps .

1. Make sure the user account is not protected (like some enterprise accounts) use some personnel G mail ID to test.
2. Make Sure the version of beta app is greater then the currently Live application
   if its not then it will not show up the review dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by typecasting the context and activity to the required form i.e application context and activity . Although it seems illogical, nothing else worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I joined the beta in the store and it showed. But just show once time.

Comment: The same for me. It showed just one time after downloading apk from internal testing. They say in docs that after that, you can install directly from Anroid Studio and test, but it never appeared again...

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered that the app must be approved from google (i.e. not having the temporary name)

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct no issue
we can follow a few steps

1. app upload following URL https://play.google.com/console/u/0/internal-app-sharing/
2. setup google play console your project setup->inter app sharing-> anyone can download select the option -> to save
   3 check your mobile internal app sharing to play store app

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but none of the steps for the solutions provided worked for me. They are all great advice and should be followed. However, if you also can't get the in-app review UI to pop up, you might want to try what I did. (I'm sure there is probably a key step in there that is the actual solution so all these steps may not be necessary.)

Ultimately, the issue was that I initially installed my app using a gmail suite email (same one I used to deploy the app if that makes a difference) and the app remained associated with that user even after switching to other users on my phone.

- Bad user is active in Google Play app
- Uninstall the app (duh)
- Go to bad user's library and remove the app
- Stop and delete data/cache for Play Store app
- (At this point I removed/re-added my good gmail user account in android settings but probably not necessary)
- Start and switch to good gmail account in Play Store app
- (If you search for the app, you should see a little note under the name saying the app is associated with the bad user account. This means it will not work right. Don't install it yet!)

This is the important part!

- Start Chrome browser, and login with good gmail account
- Go to email and CLICK ON THE LINK TO INSTALL THE APP FROM YOUR INVITE to test it (notice that was in all caps so must be important)
- The app should now be associated on this device with the good account and you should see the in-app review pop-up UI

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this problem:

I used `applicationContext` and now it is working and displaying just fine.

For some reason, the `context` and `activity` don't work, only `applicationContext`.

Answer (score -1):

Documentation says that it won't be shown every time you request it since it has quota restrictions:
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review#quotas

I just included it in my project and it showed the dialog only one time.  It is a little inconvenient since we don't have any controls over it.

Also, I noticed that if you try to show the dialog again and again, navigation bar starts blinking (like it wants to show the dialog but it gets dismissed).

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback. I'm aware of the quota restrictions. But for me it did not show even the first time and I used different accounts who never rated the app or downloaded the app for first time. So this made me believe maybe there is some other issue.

Comment: @PetrNalevka I am even facing the same issue.
I am getting the callback for complete and then success.
But no review dialogs are seen. I have made sure to use a release build and also pointing to a versionCode that is currently active in the playStore.

Answer (score -4):

Please test using FakeReviewManager :)

ReviewManager manager = new FakeReviewManager(context);

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test

Comment: The FakeReviewManage is only used for unit testing or integration purpose, meaning that it will fake the behavior of the API once the review is completed.