# In-App Review : How to correctly implement it

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-core

I have been trying to implement the In-App Review launched recently by Google.
I am not able to see the review dialog even though I get a response stating that the flow was successful.

```
    ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this);
    Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();
    request.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            ReviewInfo reviewInfo = task.getResult();
    Task<Void> flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(activity, reviewInfo);
    flow.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

           //** I reach here with the status of task as successful.

    });
        } else {
            // There was some problem, continue regardless of the result.
        }
    });
```

Should I publish my app update directly on play store? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think there is some obfuscation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63650212/10117882

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play Core In-App Review API not showing the Review Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286540/play-core-in-app-review-api-not-showing-the-review-activity)

Answer (score 4):

To see the review dialog you have to install your app from the Play Store, either from an internal test track or internal app sharing, see:

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test

Additionally it's not mentioned in the docs but we could only see the review dialog with a "release" build and not a "debug" one.

Answer (score 0):

After updating the play core library to the latest version, I can able to test the review flow with the debug build on a physical device.(don't test it with emulator)

See play core release notes [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/release-notes)