# Google Play In-App Review free text marked as required

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-core

I'm implementing Google Play In-App Review.

After following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65333746/500105
I can now see the popup asking for the review.

The issue is that after I rate the app, the review option is shown, but as can be seen in the attached image, the text part is marked as Required and not Optional as it should.

Is that something I can control with the API? Will it appear the same in the production environment?

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate how did you solved this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't find a solution/explanation for this one.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this happens because you are taking part in a testing track.

Therefore, instead of leaving an actual review, you are actually giving private beta feedback.

If you try on the production track it should be fine.