# How to set the google in-app comment optional?

Tags: kotlin, google-play

The in-app dialog is working fine on my device but it's has required comment. the submit button will not be enable if the user does not have inputted a comment. I want the user have only optional comment on the app.

[image]

```
fun inAppReview() {
    val reviewManager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(mContext)
    val requestReviewFlow = reviewManager.requestReviewFlow()
    requestReviewFlow.addOnCompleteListener { request ->
        if (request.isSuccessful) {
            // We got the ReviewInfo object
            val reviewInfo = request.result
            val flow = reviewManager.launchReviewFlow(mContext as Activity, reviewInfo)
            flow.addOnCompleteListener {
                // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
                // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no
                // matter the result, we continue our app flow.
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("Error: ", request.exception.toString())
            // There was some problem, continue regardless of the result.
        }
    }
}
```

Dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/66568269/7867180: it is required only when you are a tester. Since, it is written "reviews are only visible to developers", it means that you are really the tester. In other cases, it will be optional as stated in docs.