# Android Studio not possible to sign production App anymore

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-signing

Over the weekend something happend, because on monday it wasn't possible anymore to make a signed production build of my App. The only thing that I installed was [Ableton Live 11](https://www.ableton.com/en/live/) but I don't see how this could be related. I use "Generate Signed Bundle / APK" to make sure the `signingConfigs` in `build.gradle` are not the problem.

When running from Android Studio it showed this:

[image]

When uploading the APK on [APKPure](https://apkpure.com/apk-signature-verification) it showed that the apk wasn't valid:

[image]

Steps that I've tried so far:

- Tried different projects, all projects are unable to sign, so it's not the specific project.
- Uninstalled Android Studio from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac).
- I've found the Signature mentioned on apkpure in `google-services.json` and I've deleted this, but same result.

Comment: Which way you build the apk? [Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) > Build APK(s)]
or [Generate Signed Bundle / APK...]

Comment: I use "Generate Signed Bundle / APK" to make sure the signingConfigs in build.gradle are not the problem.

Comment: When you build via "Generate Signed Bundle / APK", didn't you change to `debug` or any other not-`release` configuration?

Comment: @JimClermonts when trying, you only tried with 1 sign or more? maybe the sig itself is corrupted, but then it shouldn't be building at all.

Comment: @xYuri I tried different projects. Same result. The problem is not in the project

Comment: @JimClermonts I am not talking about the project, am talking about the signature (the keystore), did you try with a new keystore?

Comment: No I have this production keystore and I don't want users to uninstall the existing App

Answer (score -1):

- You probably changed the KeyStore of your app.
- Make sure that in `build.gradle`, the signingConfig-attribute of `debug{}` and `release{}` in `buildTypes{}` have the same value and `debug{}` has the attribute `debuggable true`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27873028

Comment: Build variant is not related to the OP, as he is Generating Signed Bundle / APK, he has to provide the sig and the path and selecting the variant manually.